# Chutzpah Typescript compiler support for ...any params

Tags: typescript, chutzpah

I'm using Chutzpah 3.2.1 command-line in my TeamCity installation, to execute some Typescript unit tests.

I'm getting this error when it tries to run:

```
[JavaScript Tests] Error: Error in [JavaScript runtime error]:
[11:31:03][JavaScript Tests] C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/fd0bdc3857f5e4c1/Claims/Web/Scripts/app/search/SearchController.ts(77,16): error TS2082: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
[11:31:03][JavaScript Tests]    Call signatures of types '(event: ng.IAngularEvent, element: JQuery) => void' and '(event: ng.IAngularEvent, ...args: any[]) => any' are incompatible:
```

This bit of code in question is:

```
 $scope.$on(EventConstants.TYPEAHEAD_SELECTED, (event: ng.IAngularEvent, suggestion: FieldTypeaheadSuggestion) => {
        this.search(false);
    });
```

The definition of $on in angular.d.ts is:

```
$on(name: string, listener: (event: IAngularEvent, ...args: any[]) => any): Function;
```

This code compiles fine within the VS2013 IDE (using the Typescript support now built into VS)

I have read in other places that some compilers complain here because the d.ts use of `...args: any[]` implies that the parameters are optional, and this conflicts with the signature of the function passed into the `$on` function, where `suggestion` is required.

However, the IDE doesn't mind this issue, so is there any way to get the Chutzpah compiler to behave in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Chutzpah's compile setting (read about it here: https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20compile%20setting&referringTitle=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File). This was released in the latest version of Chutzpah and it allows you to tell Chutzpah how to compile the code to JS (or if it should just assume the JS is compile externally and where to find it).

This is the recommended approach for working with TypeScript and Chutzpah now.

Comment: Where should the Chutzpah.json file be? Does it go in the same folder as chutzpah.console.exe? I don't have one there. If there isn't one, what defaults are used? If I introduce a config file, do I need to specify all the defaults in it?

Comment: Please read the documentation [here](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File&referringTitle=Documentation) and see the samples [here](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Compilation/).

In short the Chutzpah.json file can be in the directory your tests are in or in any folder above them.

Answer (score 0):

Check Igorbek's trick here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/1467

This seems more of a typescript issue then a Chutzpah problem.

Give this a try

```
$scope.$on(EventConstants.TYPEAHEAD_SELECTED, (event: ng.IAngularEvent, suggestion?: FieldTypeaheadSuggestion) => {
    this.search(false);
});
```

The

```
...args: any[]
```

signature expects 0, 1, or more arguments. Your example specifies exactly one arguments. Use "?" to specify these are optional arguments like so:

$scope.$on('eventName', (event: ng.IAngularEvent, arg1?, arg2?)